# dplyr group_by_ lazy .drop = F

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to incorporate the `drop = F` into the following `dplyr function`

```
dspreadN = function(data, ...) {
  data %>% group_by_(.dots = lazyeval::lazy_dots(...), .drop = F) %>%
    summarise(n = n()*100) %>% spread(value, n, fill = 0)
}
```

Basically, the function transform this

```
   id x
1   1 A
2   1 A
3   1 A
4   1 A
5   2 A
6   2 A
7   2 B
8   2 B
9   3 A
10  3 A
11  3 B
12  3 A
```

into that

```
    id drop      A     B
  <dbl> <lgl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1 FALSE   400     0
2     2 FALSE   200   200
3     3 FALSE   300   100
```

I use the function in this way `dff %>% dspreadN(id, value = x)`

(my real example is much more complicated that why I need the `dplyr function`).

What I would like is to keep all the levels of the `x` variable, here the `C` is missing.

```
    id      A     B    C
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   400     0   0
2     2   200   200   0
3     3   300   100   0
```

Why is the `drop = F` not working?

```
library(tidyverse)

# data
dff = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4), 
                 x = c('A','A','A','A', 'A','A','B','B', 'A','A','B','A', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'))

# remove the case to keep the C level 
dff = dff[dff$id != 4, ]
```

Comment: is `x` a factor?

Comment: you shouldn't use `group_by_` because it is deprecated. You should use `group_by`

Comment: What is `value` in `spread`? It appears nowhere before

Answer (score 2):

- You can use `.drop = FALSE` argument in `count` instead of `group_by`.
- `group_by` + `summarise` with `n()`  is equal to `count`.
- `spread` has been deprecated in favour of `pivot_wider`.

Thanks to @Edo for useful tips in improving the post

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dspreadN = function(data, ...) {
  data %>%
    count(id, x, .drop = FALSE, wt = n() * 100) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = x, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
}

dspreadN(dff, id, x)

#     id     A     B     C
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1   400     0     0
#2     2   200   200     0
#3     3   300   100     0
```

Comment: you can set up `.drop = FALSE` in `count` and you will not need to set `drop = FALSE` in `spread`

Comment: also, `mutate` is not necessary since you could write `count` in this way: `count(..., wt = n()*100)`

Comment: @Edo Thanks for your comments. I improved the post accordingly.